# Want to Change css of third child element n jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created something like this, but it's not working. If I assign it to `li` then it works fine.

```js
function activetab() {
  $(".nav-tabs li a:nth-child(3)").css("color", "red");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">xyzv</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">xyzv</a></li>
</ul>
<button onclick="activetab()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Every single one of those `a` elements is the _only_ child of its parent. _“if I assign it to li then it works fine”_ - well the LI have siblings, are not the only child ...

Comment: You're looking for the 3rd `li`, not the 3rd `a` : `.nav-tabs li:nth-child(3) a`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because all the `a` elements are at the 0th index of their parent `li` elements. If you want the third one, you need to declare the `:nth-child` selector on the `li` elements instead.

Also note that you shouldn't be using `on*` event attributes as they are very outdated. As you've included jQuery in the page, use that to attach your event handlers. You should also avoid using `css()` where possible, as it ties the UI and JS logic too closely when they should be entirely separate entities. To achieve that, use `addClass()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li:nth-child(3) a").addClass('foo');
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">xyzv</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">xyzv</a></li>
</ul>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. on thing can I pass a variable instead of a number in nth-child.like this nth-child(numb)

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate that value to the selector as you would any normal string.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped. That also stands for your previous questions too, as I can see you've never accepted any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function activetab(){
  $(".nav-tabs li:nth-child(3) a").css("color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
$(".nav-tabs li a:nth-child(3) a").css("color", "red");
```